# cakePHP subquery in FROM

Tags: mysql, cakephp, subquery

I need help to understand if something like this is posible on cakePHP...

I have a MYSQL query that retrive the information on the way it's needed, and it looks something like this:

```
SELECT *
FROM 
(SELECT id ...)
JOIN
(SELECT id ...)
GROUP BY ...
```

So what I need to know if there is anyway on cakePHP to resolve the first FROM subquery.

I could break the query in two but I want to know if it can be solved in cakePHP using one Model->find command.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

It cannot because your first "table" (in the `FROM` clause) is based on the model of the `find`.  That being said

1. You can take your `FROM`  subquery and make a SQL view out of it. Then create a Cakephp based on that view.
2. If your first subquery does not have a `GROUP BY`, the entire query can probably can be re-written without the subquery.

Comment: Hi, Thanks @AgRizzo  
  
So the "datasource" inside the  `FROM`clause are tied to the model on the  `find` command.... that's crossed for my mind, but I thought that maybe there was some way to work around this.  
  
The subquery inside the `FORM` is not using `GROUP BY`

Comment: @bRuNuShky - There is also the [query](http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/models/retrieving-your-data.html#model-query) method, but your question had stated that you wanted to use the `find` method.

Comment: Hi and thanks for your information, finally I was able to solve the query just applying your second advice, also I was able to resolve the second subquery (that inside the join) using the `buildStatement` method and get something useful for my app.